# Nested if formula in excel skipping a step

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to create a formula that:

looks in F4, if blank look in B4, if that is blank add 120 days to K4 if not blank add 120 days to B4

If F4 is not blank add 60 days THEN if those any of those dates are great than todays date enter Y in the current cell otherwise leave blank.

When i run this its fine unless column F4 is blank, it seems to skip over deciding if the updated date is greater than today. What am i missing?

```
=IF(IF(ISBLANK($F4),IF(ISBLANK($B4),$K4+120,$B4+120),$F4+60>TODAY()),"Y","")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirements correctly and if you have the newest version of Excel, `LET` will help keep everything organized.

```
=LET(x, 

IF(ISBLANK($F4),
IF(ISBLANK($B4),$K4+120,$B4+120),
$F4+60),

IF(x>TODAY(), "Y", ""))
```

If not, then you will need to test each individually.

Try:

```
IF(ISBLANK($F4),
IF(IF(ISBLANK($B4),$K4+120,$B4+120)>TODAY(), "Y", ""),
IF($F4+60>TODAY(), "Y", ""))
```

Comment: THATS IT, thanks.... i was rewriting it and just thought, wait this is only comparing today to f4, doh. Thanks so much